# Named enumarations in C++

Tags: c++, enums

Am using named enumerations in my code as shown below.

```
namespace Config 
{
    enum class SubscribersIpVersion
    {                              
        Dhcpv6,                    
        DualStack,                 
        DualStackDhcpv6,           
        DualStackSlaac,            
        Ipv4,                      
        Ipv6,                      
        Slaac,                     
    };
};
```

In one of my class, a function is returned to the IP version

```
class xxxx
{
...
public:
SubscribersIpVersion getIpVersion() {return ipVersion;}
private:
SubscribersIpVersion ipVersion;
};
```

But the following if condition is failing

```
if (!isIpv6 && (pSubGroup->getIpVersion() == Config::SubscribersIpVersion::Ipv6 ||          
                     pSubGroup->getIpVersion() == Config::SubscribersIpVersion::Slaac ||         
                     pSubGroup->getIpVersion() == Config::SubscribersIpVersion::Dhcpv6 ||        
                     pSubGroup->getIpVersion() == Config::SubscribersIpVersion::DualStack ||     
                     pSubGroup->getIpVersion() == Config::SubscribersIpVersion::DualStackSlaac ||
                     pSubGroup->getIpVersion() == Config::SubscribersIpVersion::DualStackDhcpv6))
```

The reason I found in gdb is,

```
(gdb) pt pSubGroup->getIpVersion()
type = enum Config::SubscribersIpVersion {Config::Dhcpv6, Config::DualStack,
    Config::DualStackDhcpv6, Config::DualStackSlaac, Config::Ipv4, Config::Ipv6,
    Config::Slaac}
(gdb) p pSubGroup->getIpVersion()
$1 = Config::DualStack
```

This is the error in gdb if I compare

```
(gdb) p pSubGroup->getIpVersion() == Config::SubscribersIpVersion::DualStack
`Config::SubscribersIpVersion' is not defined as an aggregate type.
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong with the above code?

Comment: What is `isIpv6`?

Comment: By the way, GDB's output is slightly wrong; apparently it doesn't fully comprehend scoped enums

Comment: Present your [MCVE].

Comment: It's just a Boolean flag

Comment: Yes, with what value?

Comment: Value is false in that comparison.  As per the scenario, since it is !isIpv6, it must match with one of the enum.  But since 'SubGroup->getIpVersion()' is 'Config::DualStack', and inside code we are comparing with 'Config::SubscribersIpVersion::DualStack' it is not matching.

Comment: Prove it........ `if` statements don't randomly stop working on their own. One of your values isn't what you think it is, or you're misinterpreting the symptoms. Without a [MCVE] we cannot tell you what that misunderstanding is.

Comment: This is what I can show for now

(gdb) p pSubGroup->getIpVersion()
$1 = Config::DualStack

(gdb) p pSubGroup->getIpVersion() == SubscribersIpVersion::DualStack
`Config::SubscribersIpVersion' is not defined as an aggregate type.
(gdb) p pSubGroup->getIpVersion() == Config::DualStack
$2 = true

My question is, why is gdb complaining about aggregate type when compilation is through

Comment: It is working for me here (I tried since I did not see anything wron with your code). BTW, wouldn't it be easier to compare `!ipv6 && pSubGroup->getIpVersion() != Config::SubscribersIpVersion::Ipv4` ?
http://ideone.com/ulMPAS

Comment: _"This is what I can show for now"_ No, present a [MCVE]. Last time asking.

Comment: @Baltasarq: That is how the code is written.

(!isIpv6 && (pSubGroup->getIpVersion() == Config::SubscribersIpVersion::Ipv6)

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: Am not sure in what best way I can present the case.  I thought the code is simple and complete.  Please suggest what changes I can make to the code to show it as complete and verifiable example.

Comment: Click on the link I gave you. Not sure why you think this is "complete". It is one `enum class` definition, and one `class` definition with `...` scattered through it. There's not even a function, let alone a `main`. It won't compile, let alone run so we can see it in action.

Comment: Oops modified my comment, it's true it was incorrect. The correction is here:  why not `!ipv6 && pSubGroup->getIpVersion() != Config::SubscribersIpVersion::Ipv4`instead?

Comment: You should actually have already created a [MCVE] as part of your own debugging, during which process you would probably have found was is almost certainly going to turn out to be some silly typo that isn't exhibited in what you've showed us

Comment: Have you checked my link? That code is working for me!
http://ideone.com/ulMPAS

Comment: Well...........?

Comment: @Baltasarq: Yes, your code is working fine.  Same sample code works fin in my environment too.  But not sure why it is failing in my actual simulator.

Comment: Explain "simulator". What version of C++ are you using in your simulator?

Comment: Have you enabled C++11 in your compiler? Named enums are a C++ 11 feature...

Comment: All:  Thanks for the support.  I found there is a logic problem in the code.  Once that is fixed, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

All: Thanks for the support. I found there is a logic problem in the code. Once that is fixed, everything is working fine.